# LM2596S heating up and drawing current

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I am trying to generate -7 V/1.3 A and +7 V/1.3 A, using two LM2596S, from a 12 V voltage.

The positive voltage is fine, but the negative one doesn't work. The first time I apply voltage to the negative LM2596S it draws about 300 mA and produces 4 V (positive) at the output and is warm (without any load).

The second time I apply input to it the output is shorted to ground and it draws no current; I think the IC died.

What am I doing wrong? I am using the configuration in the datasheet. I have tried with both TAB connected to ground and TAB unconnected. I am using a 12 V/5 A to supply the input.

[image]

Comment: U3 is going to let current from +12V, through the diode, through the inductor, straight to ground - until this magically causes the feedback voltage to rise up to whatever voltage it's supposed to be, which it never will. By contrast, when U7 lets current through, it *does* cause the feedback voltage to rise.

Comment: If we are done here you should consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Yes, Problem solved. seemed like my inductor couldn't handle the initial current that LM2596 drew. I used a 220uH, 4A toroidal inductor. I don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this: -

[image]

TAB needs to be connected to where GND is connected.

[image]

GND = Ground

Comment: If TAB is internally connected to GND pin, it should have worked with the TAB unconnected. Probably there is another problem with this circuit too. Maybe the choice of capacitors, inductor, resistors etc. I am not sure.

Comment: You possibly harmed the device the first time and thereafter you are suffering with a faulty device. Nonetheless, double check all connections and don't expect the device to operate properly under breadboard conditions @Fateme

Comment: Hello, I changed the device and I used a resistor divider of 1k and 4.7k, the device is not overheating and seems to be normal but I only get -1.3V in the output. It's like I am getting the inverted bandgap reference in the output! I changed R7 to other values. I still only have about -1.5V!

Comment: Don't expect the device to operate properly under breadboard conditions @Fateme